# iterate through list of files and print a count of rows for each of them in a dict (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a list of files(csv) and I would like to count the number of rows for each of them. Finally print each count into a dictionary.

Any suggestions/explanations?

thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you make an attempt yourself, and edit your code into the question. Stackoverflow is about helping people to get their code right, not writing it for them.

Comment: I tried to write my code. It said there was a problem with indentation.

Comment: My code: mylist=[]   files=[file1,file2]  filedata={filename:open(filename, 'r') filename in files]  for i in filedata:  for line in filedata:  mylist.append(line)   print mylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code:
you have some confusion with { and ] and you forgot FOR, where you are trying to create dictionary comprehension.

```
filedata={filename:open(filename, 'r') filename in files]
```

Should be:

```
filedata={filename:open(filename, 'r') for filename in files}
```

And your task is to create a dictionary, but you somehow create list.

Working version of your code

```
mylist=[]
files=['file1.csv','file2.csv']
filedata={filename:open(filename, 'r') for filename in files}
for i in filedata:
    count = 0
    for line in filedata[i]:
            count+=1
    mylist.append(count)
print mylist
```

You can use csv module to open your files.
Create a defaultdict and everytime you read a line, add 1 to your dictionary.

Something like this:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
files = ['file1.csv'
    ,'file2.csv']
final_dict = defaultdict(int)
for file in files:
    with open(file,'rb') as current:
            reader= csv.reader(current, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                    final_dict[file]+=1
print  final_dict
```

Comment: Please explain why, code-only answers are not helpful and against SO policy.